# Use result of function in html img tag

Tags: javascript, html, function

I try to use the result of a javascript function to fill in the 'src' value of IMG tags.
I want to use this on many places in same page, otherwise I think I could use an ID in the IMG tag and change src with getelementbyid.

The idea is to load images depending on the size of the userscreen.

The code which does not give me correct result:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function path_images(image)
        {
            var s = screen.width;
            path = (s<1080) ? "small":"large";
            return path + "/" + image;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Some text</h1>
    <img alt="error" src=path_images("someimage.png")>
    <img alt="error" src=path_images("someotherimage.png")>
</body>
```

Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: FYI, you don't need brackets around `s<1080`.

Comment: you can't put a js function in the src attribute

Comment: Use [the picture element](http://responsiveimages.org/demos/variable-width/index.html) with a JavaScript shim. Don't reinvent the wheel. Especially when you level of JS skill is at the point where you are trying to write JavaScript somewhere the browser is expecting a URL.

Comment: @ron, css media queries can help you, also you don't need js for this

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. It selects all elements with tag img and changes eachs SRC. If you want to change the source of one single image you should use ids or any other identifier.

```
function changeSource() 
{
  aImgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); 
  for ( var index in aImgs )
     aImgs[ index ].src = path_images( image_here );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab the images:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
```

Convert the nodelist to an array and loop over it updating the `src`.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(images).forEach(function (img) {
  img.src = path_images(img.getAttribute('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@ron for this purpose you just need to call a function on body onload, what this function will do? this function will very much get the screen width first and after the decision whether there would be small or large it will grab all the images coming at the page along with their src attributes, then loop over each (maybe foreach) of them in the same body onload function and concat the small or large before the path and this will fullfill your requirment.

Well function can't be call on img src tag it can be at onclick event. each javascript function is called at some event.